# Count word occurrences in a text field with LINQ

Tags: .net, linq, pattern-matching

How can i get the occurrences count of a Word in a database text field With LINQ ?

Keyword token sample : ASP.NET

EDIT 4 :

Database Records :

Record 1 : [TextField] = "Blah blah blah **ASP.NET** bli bli bli **ASP.NET** blu **ASP.NET** yop yop **ASP.NET**"

Record 2 : [TextField] = "Blah blah blah bli bli bli blu **ASP.NET** yop yop **ASP.NET**"

Record 3 : [TextField] = "Blah **ASP.NET** blah **ASP.NET** blah **ASP.NET** bli **ASP.NET** bli bli **ASP.NET** blu **ASP.NET** yop yop **ASP.NET**"

So

Record 1 Contains 4 occurrence of "ASP.NET" keyword

Record 2 Contains 2 occurrence of "ASP.NET" keyword

Record 3 Contains 7 occurrence of "ASP.NET" keyword

Collection Extraction IList < RecordModel >  (ordered by word count descending)

- Record 3
- Record 1
- Record 2

LinqToSQL should be the best, but LinqToObject too :)

NB : No issue about the "." of ASP.NET keyword (this is not the goal if this question)

Comment: Are you trying to do this on the database side using Linq to SQL? Or are you working with a subset of data on the client side (ie. Linq to Objects over a collection)?

Comment: I've already fetched a subset of data containing keywords. So now i'm working in Linq To Object over collection yep :)

Comment: But i think that's should be better to build an all in one LinqToSQL query for performance maybe ... Instead of pre-fetch a subset of data that contains each keywords and then perform that operation in memory ?

Comment: You could write a database function for it, I can't imagine L2S being smart enough to build something like that in SQL.

Comment: SQL is rather bad at string manipulation, it's sting functions are quite primitive, better to get your text as text and work on it in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex handles this nicely. You can use the `\b` metacharacter to anchor the word boundary, and escape the keyword to avoid unintended use of special regex characters. It also handles the cases of trailing periods, commas, etc.

```
string[] records =
{
    "foo ASP.NET bar", "foo bar",
    "foo ASP.NET? bar ASP.NET",
    "ASP.NET foo ASP.NET! bar ASP.NET",
    "ASP.NET, ASP.NET ASP.NET, ASP.NET"
};
string keyword = "ASP.NET";
string pattern = @"\b" + Regex.Escape(keyword) + @"\b";
var query = records.Select((t, i) => new
            {
                Index = i,
                Text = t,
                Count = Regex.Matches(t, pattern).Count
            })
            .OrderByDescending(item => item.Count);

foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Record {0}: {1} occurrences - {2}",
        item.Index, item.Count, item.Text);
}
```

Voila! :)

Answer (score 4):

Edit 2: I see you updated the question, changes things a bit, word counts per word eh? Try this:

```
string input = "some random text: how many times does each word appear in some random text, or not so random in this case";
char[] separators = new char[]{ ' ', ',', ':', ';', '?', '!', '\n', '\r', '\t' };

var query = from s in input.Split( separators )
            where s.Length > 0
            group s by s into g
            let count = g.Count()
            orderby count descending
            select new {
                Word = g.Key,
                Count = count
            };
```

Since you are wanting words that might have a "." in them (e.g. "ASP.NET") I've excluded that from the separator list, unfortunately that will pollute some words as a sentence like "Blah blah blah. Blah blah." would show "blah" with a count of 3 and "blah." with a count of 2. You'll need to think of what cleaning strategy you want here, e.g. if the "." has a letter either side it counts as part of a word, otherwise it's whitespace. That kind of logic is best done with some RegEx.

Comment: What if the word is have and you have haven't in your text? It would depend on the requirements if your solution would work.

Comment: i don't really need the count of a specific word, but a data extraction ordered by the max count of a specific word count founded in each records

Comment: Same issues with [.] would also apply to ['], assuming you want to have quote marks excluded except when they're part of a word. This issue is probably best split into another question since you'll want the best regex to extract words (if there isn't already a question answering this).

Comment: Once you have a nice regex that matches words with [.] and/or ['] in a way you like, simply replace the "input.Split( separators )" with "Regex.Matches( input, wordFindingRegEx )" and I think "s"  (our string) would have to become "match.Value" in in 4 places. With the correct RegEx you could also remove the where clause.

Comment: Timothy > not exactly what i want, i've updated my question, hope it should be more clear ...

Answer (score 1):

Use String.Split() to turn the string into an array of words, then use LINQ to filter this list returning only the words you want, and then check the count of the result, like this:

```
myDbText.Split(' ').Where(token => token.Equals(word)).Count();
```

Comment: The word could be followed by a period, or have a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

You could `Regex.Matches(input, pattern).Count` or you could do the following:

```
int count = 0; int startIndex = input.IndexOf(word);
while (startIndex != -1) { ++count; startIndex = input.IndexOf(word, startIndex + 1); }
```

using LINQ here would be ugly

Answer (score 0):

I know this is more than the original question asked, but it still matches the subject and I'm including it for others who search on this question later.  This does not require that the whole word be matched in the strings that are searched, however it can be easily modified to do so with code from Ahmad's post.

```
//use this method to order objects and keep the existing type
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    List<TwoFields> tfList = new List<TwoFields>();
    tfList.Add(new TwoFields { one = "foo ASP.NET barfoo bar", two = "bar" });
    tfList.Add(new TwoFields { one = "foo bar foo", two = "bar" });
    tfList.Add(new TwoFields { one = "", two = "barbarbarbarbar" });

    string keyword = "bar";
    string pattern = Regex.Escape(keyword);
    tfList = tfList.OrderByDescending(t => Regex.Matches(string.Format("{0}{1}", t.one, t.two), pattern).Count).ToList();

    foreach (TwoFields tf in tfList)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", tf.one, tf.two));
    }

    Console.Read();
  }
}


//a class with two string fields to be searched on
public class TwoFields
{
  public string one { get; set; }
  public string two { get; set; }
}
```

.

```
//same as above, but uses multiple keywords
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    List<TwoFields> tfList = new List<TwoFields>();
    tfList.Add(new TwoFields { one = "one one, two; three four five", two = "bar" });
    tfList.Add(new TwoFields { one = "one one two three", two = "bar" });
    tfList.Add(new TwoFields { one = "one two three four five five", two = "bar" });

    string keywords = " five one    ";
    string keywordsClean = Regex.Replace(keywords, @"\s+", " ").Trim(); //replace multiple spaces with one space

    string pattern = Regex.Escape(keywordsClean).Replace("\\ ","|"); //escape special chars and replace spaces with "or"
    tfList = tfList.OrderByDescending(t => Regex.Matches(string.Format("{0}{1}", t.one, t.two), pattern).Count).ToList();

    foreach (TwoFields tf in tfList)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", tf.one, tf.two));
    }

    Console.Read();
  }
}

public class TwoFields
{
  public string one { get; set; }
  public string two { get; set; }
}
```